# Como cambiar el tipo columna en datatable integrado con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

Hola tengo un datable el cual funciona todo correcto hasta que filtro mediante un boton ese mismo datatable. Lo que me hace mal es que en la columna referencia como podeis apreciar en la primera foto el incio es correcto, su codigo esta compuesto por letras y numeros, en cambio en la 2 foto esta tomada despues de filtrar el datatable y por arte de magia las letras han desaparecido de la columna referencia:

**Imagen 1 correcto**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen 2 despues del filtro ERROR**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo creo que el problema es que cuando hago el filtro la columna cambia a tipo Number por lo que me borra las letras que contiene dicho articulo, os pongo el fragmento del controller del datatable, la funcion de filtrar y el datatable del index blade.

**Fragmento controller datatable -Este es el fragmento que carga la primera carga del datatable incial y esta funcionando bien(imagen 1)**

```
return Datatables::of(Movimiento::all())

       
        ->addColumn('id', function ($movimiento) {
            // return $movimiento->referencia;
            return $movimiento->articulo->codigo;
        }).......
```

**Funcion Filtro de datatable, el LOG funciona correcto ya que me devuelve el conjunto de letras y numeros,**

```
 public function busquedaFechas(Request $request)
{
   


     

        $articulo_id = $request->articulo;
        $desde = $request->desde;
        $hasta = $request->hasta;

        // Log::info($desde);
        // Log::info($hasta);

        if ($articulo_id == null) {
            $resultadoBusqueda = Movimiento::whereBetween('fecha', [$desde, $hasta])->get();
        } else {
            $resultadoBusqueda = Movimiento::whereBetween('fecha', [$desde, $hasta])- 
            >where('articulo_id', $articulo_id)->get();
        }

        foreach ($resultadoBusqueda as $resu) {
            $resu['articulo_id'] = $resu['articulo']['descripcion'];
            $resu['almacen_id'] = $resu['almacen']['nombre'];
            $resu['albaran_id'] = $resu['albaran']['referencia'];
            $referencia=$resu['articulo']['codigo'];
            
           
            $resu['id'] = $referencia;
            Log::info("codigo articulo");
            Log::info( $resu['id'] = $referencia);// Log muestra CORRECTO  
        }
        
        Log::info("resultadoBusqueda");
        Log::info($resultadoBusqueda);

     

        return response()->json(['success' => 'busqueda correcta', 'resultadoBusqueda' => $resultadoBusqueda]);
    
}
```

**Datatble pintado en el blade de laravel**

```
@include('index',array(
            'id' => 'movimiento',
            'action' => route('movimiento.table'),
            'config' => [
            'order' => '[[ 1,"asc"]]',
            'pageLength' => 100,
            'responsive' => 'false',
            'scrollX' => 'true',
            ],
            'columns' => array(

            array(
            'id' => 'fecha',
            'name' => 'Fecha',
            ),

            array(
            'id' => 'id',
            'name' => 'Referencia', //Este campo da error al filtrar el datatable ya que elimina las letras de los articulos
            'type'=>'text'//NO FUNCIONA AUN PONIENDOLO TYPE TEXT
            ),  

            array(
            'id' => 'articulo_id',
            'name' => 'Articulo',
            ),

            array(
            'id' => 'cantidad',
            'name' => 'Cantidad',
            ),

            array(
            'id' => 'balance',
            'name' => 'Balance',
            ),

            array(
            'id' => 'almacen_id',
            'name' => 'Almacén',
            ),

            array(
            'id' => 'referencia',
            'name' => 'Documento',
            ),

            array(
            'id' => 'razon',
            'name' => 'Razón',
            ),

            ))
            )
```

**Edito el post para poner la funcion javascript que realiza el filtro**

```
$( "#filtrarFechas" ).click(function() {
    var url = "{!!route('movimiento.busquedaFechas')!!}";
    // console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url, // This is what I have updated
            data: $("#form_filtrarBusqueda").serialize(),
            success:function(data) {
                console.log("datos");
                console.log(data);
                if(data.success=='busqueda correcta')
                {
                    // console.log("datos");
                    // console.log(data.resultadoBusqueda);
                    // // console.log(data.resultadoBusqueda[0]['referencia']);
                    // console.log("findatos");

                    var datosTabla = $('#movimiento-table').DataTable();
                    datosTabla.clear();
                    datosTabla.rows.add(data.resultadoBusqueda);
                    datosTabla.draw();

                    $("#errores").empty();
                }

                if (data.errors != "" && data.errors != null) {
                    $("#errores").empty();
                    var erroresAlertas = "<br><div class=\"alert alert-danger \" style=\"float:left;width:50%\" >";
                    jQuery.each(data.errors, function(key, value) {
                        erroresAlertas = erroresAlertas + '<p>' + value + '</p>';
                    });
                    erroresAlertas += '</div>';
                    // console.log("errores");
                    // console.log(erroresAlertas);
                    $("#errores").append(erroresAlertas);
                }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Cuando dices "después del filtro", te refieres al filtro que tú hiciste o al filtro por defecto de DataTables?

Comment: Al filtro que yo hice, en el código JavaScript llama a la función busquedafechas mediante AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que veo es que en este foreach

```
foreach ($resultadoBusqueda as $resu) {
    $resu['articulo_id'] = $resu['articulo']['descripcion'];
    $resu['almacen_id'] = $resu['almacen']['nombre'];
    $resu['albaran_id'] = $resu['albaran']['referencia'];
    $referencia=$resu['articulo']['codigo'];

    $resu['id'] = $referencia;
    Log::info("codigo articulo");
    Log::info( $resu['id'] = $referencia);// Log muestra CORRECTO  
}

return response()->json(['success' => 'busqueda correcta', 'resultadoBusqueda' => $resultadoBusqueda]);
```

no estás modificando la variable que devuelves `$resultadoBusqueda`, solo estás asignado valores a otra variable `$resu` que no usas para nada.

Para modificar la variable que retornas, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
foreach ($resultadoBusqueda as $key => $resu) {
    $resultadoBusqueda[$key]['articulo_id'] = $resu['articulo']['descripcion'];
    $resultadoBusqueda[$key]['almacen_id'] = $resu['almacen']['nombre'];
    $resultadoBusqueda[$key]['albaran_id'] = $resu['albaran']['referencia'];
    $resultadoBusqueda[$key]['id'] = $resu['articulo']['codigo'];
}

return response()->json([
    'success' => 'busqueda correcta', 
    'resultadoBusqueda' => $resultadoBusqueda
]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, en llegar a casa le pego un vistazo y te digo